# How to target the last anchor element covering a list item inside and unordered list

Tags: html, css

I previously had the anchor element inside of the list item and could target it using "nth-child(4)" but as soon as I placed the anchor element outside of the list item to make the clickable area bigger it became untargetable. Any suggestion on how to target that particular element?

```css
section.social-section ul a li {
    width: 22%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #e2e0e0;
    margin-right: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
}

section.social-section ul.group a:nth-child(4) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Social section -->
<section class="social-section">
  <ul class="group">
    <a href="#">
      <li>facebook</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li>twitter</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li>pinterest</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li>google+</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: first of all what i would say is its not correct to keep <li> element inside <a> because <li> is supposed to be directly inside <ul>.

Comment: Bro, this is not a valid way to use HTML Ul, Li's I think you should use `<a>` it in side the `<li>` and then try to style your anchor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems here:

- You *can't* swap the positions of your `a` and `li` elements like that. The only children a `ul` can contain are `li` elements. The only valid structure for such a list is `ul > li > a`.
- Validity aside, the reason your rules no longer match is because your first rule is still targeting `li` elements, but your second rule targets `a` elements. They're targeting different elements, so no overriding is taking place.

You can make the clickable area bigger without altering your HTML by moving some of the CSS properties such as padding to the `a` elements, as well as making them blocks:

```css
section.social-section ul li {
    width: 22%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #e2e0e0;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

section.social-section ul.group li:nth-child(4) {
    margin-right: 0;
}

section.social-section ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Social section -->
<section class="social-section">
    <ul class="group">
        <li><a href="#">facebook</a>
        <li><a href="#">twitter</a>
        <li><a href="#">pinterest</a>
        <li><a href="#">google+</a>
    </ul>
</section>
```

(Note that moving the padding declaration causes the width of your `li` elements to be reduced, but for the purposes of this answer I'm ignoring this side-effect.)

Comment: it would be better to close all `li` tags

Comment: I knew somebody was going to say that. No, it's not going to make a difference whether you put the end tags there or not, unless you're displaying them inline (in which case including them would actually be *worse*, not better).

Answer (score 1):

As the comments rightly point out, the immediate children of `ul` tag must always be zero or more `li` tags.

However, you say that you are doing this to increase the clickable area. You can do that by putting the `a` tags back inside the `li` tags, and then make the `a` tags `display : inline-block`. You could then apply `width : 100%` and `height : 100%` on `a` to increase the clickable area (which would then be equal to the entire area of the `li`). In this manner, you can use `nth-child()` to target the 4th child.

Your code becomes :

HTML

```
<!-- Social section -->
        <section class="social-section">
            <ul class="group">
                <li><a href="#">facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">pinterest</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">google+</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
```

CSS

```
section.social-section ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

section.social-section ul.group li:nth-child(4) a {
    display: inline-block;
    height : 100%; //not absolutely required
    height : 100%; //not absolutely required
}
```

You can add CSS properties to position the list as you require.